# Missing colladadom - Ros groovy source compilation on archlinux

Tags: ros, opencv, urdf, pcl, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to install Ros for the past 3 days. I couldnt compile the collada-parser because of it i couldnt compile other packages too..urdf all..

The error is mainly related to **colladadom** package which was previously present in robot_model fuerte was not available in the repo now.

I also tried compiling the colladadom package from their website. But I couldnt compile that packages too because some boost library version issues..

And I also have the problem of compiling PCL & opencv .. But I have both the libraries compiled from their sources. So I deleted those stacks.

I dont want to clutter the post by pasting any errors.

**Has anyone successfully compiled the ros_groovy on archlinux? Can it be or not?**
I mean the desktop version or robot version.not the bare_bones one,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52785/missing-colladadom---ros-groovy-source-compilation-on-archlinux/) by [myth](https://answers.ros.org/users/4005/myth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-22**:
I'm attempting to compile groovy from sources on a Pandaboard.
I'm trying with the *mobile* variant.

PCL I just moved out from the sources, I'm not sure I need that.
Collada was missing dae.h, I sourced it from the fuerte install I have on my laptop.

Which variant are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to install ROS Groovy on Arch Linux, the easiest way is to [use AUR packages](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Arch#Method_1:_Using_the_AUR_Packages).

There is something that you need to realize: packaging ROS Groovy under Arch Linux can get quite complicated since it's a rolling release and Groovy is already outdated. This is especially true for complex libraries such as PCL or Gazebo that pull tons of dependencies.

Most of the packages are made/maintained by two people ([zootboy](https://github.com/zootboy/arch-ros-stacks) and I), which is why it's not foolproof, so feedback is always welcome. If a problem happens when installing packages, try to contact the maintainers (you can leave a message on the related AUR package page).

As for [collada-dom](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/collada-dom/), [PCL](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pcl-ros/), [opencv](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/opencv/), [collada_parser](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-groovy-collada-parser/) or [collada_urdf](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-groovy-collada-urdf/), official packages and/or AUR packages exist.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1